# Tighten axis of rotation in PointerLock

Tags: three.js

For some reason, when in pointer lock mode, the rotation on mouse move isn't tight around an axis, where the rotation ends up translating the camera quite a far distance as well as rotating.

Any clues on how to tighten the axis of rotation will be a ton of help!

example: https://s3.amazonaws.com/id.rsa.pub/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `initGraphics()` function you don't need those lines:

```
camera.position.x = 10;
camera.position.y = -8;
camera.position.z =  1;
```

if you want to set start position of the camera then you have to set it as

```
controls.getObject().position.set( 10, -8, 1);
```